# How to multiply the elements of each site of tensor products to each other while using symbolic representation?

Tags: symbolic, tensors, products

If I have, say three sites in a symbolic operator which is of the form A = a⊗1⊗c and I want it to act on another operator B = a1⊗b⊗1 in order to find the commutator A.B - B.A, the result I expect would be A.B = a.a1⊗b⊗c, but I am unable to achieve such a result using the regular A.B command. A.B gives a⊗c.a1⊗b. I would also like to know how I can expand the dot product to multiple terms if they exist. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried the following:

A = TensorProduct[a, 1, c]

B = TensorProduct[a1, b, 1]

A.B

The output it gives is a⊗c.a1⊗b but the output I expect is a.a1⊗b⊗c

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps you can give some examples of formatted code you have tried ? This makes it much easier for others to try to work on answering your question

Comment: @Dunlop Edited as instructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) will work with symbolic tensors, although it needs some help from [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand). First, set some assumptions on your tensors:

```
$Assumptions = (a | a1 | b | c) ∈ Matrices[{n, n}];
```

Then, your example is:

```
A = KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[n], c];
B = KroneckerProduct[a1, b, IdentityMatrix[n]];

A.B
```

> KroneckerProduct[a, IdentityMatrix[n], c].KroneckerProduct[a1, b,
> IdentityMatrix[n]]

Using [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) produces your desired result:

```
TensorExpand[A.B]
```

> KroneckerProduct[a.a1, b, c]

Comment: Thank you very much!